# how to make a relationship 1-1 in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, shared-primary-key

*My question is*

What is correct to make a relationship 1-1 in MySQL?

The data in the child table must be unique
Exists confusing information on the internet about doing this.
In my opinion the first form is correct because it is easier.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.users;
CREATE TABLE test.users(

    idUser CHAR( 5 ) BINARY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR( 40 ) NOT NULL,
    lastName VARCHAR( 25 ) NOT NULL,
    maternalSurname VARCHAR( 25 ) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY( idUser )

)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.activities;
CREATE TABLE test.activities(

    user CHAR( 5 ) BINARY NOT NULL,
    sessionActive BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    live DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    attempt TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,

    PRIMARY KEY( user ),

    FOREIGN KEY( user ) REFERENCES users( idUser )
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Another way I found to do

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.users;
CREATE TABLE test.users(

    idUser CHAR( 5 ) BINARY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR( 40 ) NOT NULL,
    lastName VARCHAR( 25 ) NOT NULL,
    maternalSurname VARCHAR( 25 ) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY( idUser )

)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.activities;
CREATE TABLE test.activities(

    idActivity INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    sessionActive BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    live DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    attempt TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    user CHAR( 5 ) BINARY NOT NULL,

    UNIQUE( user ),

    PRIMARY KEY( idActivity ),

    INDEX( user ),
    FOREIGN KEY( user ) REFERENCES users( idUser )
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**what is the correct**

Greetings from México!!!!

Comment: 1-m and 1-1 could be coded exactly the same. What you have here are different ways to choose index and PK, and this is not an issue specific to 1-1 relationship. Note that if you choose a PK of the child other than the PK of the parent, you need to determine how to make that key unique.

Comment: Normally for 1-1 relationships you create a column in one table that references the primary key of another. There's no need for an intermediate table except for M-M relationships. I think you're doing it mostly right here, but having `CHAR(5) BINARY` as your primary key is more than a little annoying. Why not just a standard-issue `INT AUTO_INCREMENT`?